# Word javascript api - Get last paragraph of each page

Tags: office-js

How can i get last paragraph of each page ?
ex: i have 10 pages (word), and now i want to insert text at the end of each pages (page: 1,2,8...).
but i don't know where is the last paragraph of each page.
i had tried with section, paragraph, document... but i don't see Page object on it.

```
Word.run(function(context) {
     var pars = context.document.???
       pars.load();
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            .....

    return context.sync();
        })
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have to work at the level of OOXML. For information about how to do that, see. [Create better add-ins for Word with Office Open XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml). Also take a look at [getOoxml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.body?view=word-js-preview#getooxml--).

Page breaks are represented in OOXML by the `<w:lastRenderedPageBreak/>` tag.

Comment: how can i use it, i had getooxml of body but i didn't see w:lastRenderedPageBreak,
any document or sample code for it